# Solve $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Solve for $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$

$$x^{6}=y^{2}+53$$

I tried but I couldn't complete

Comment: $x=\pm3,y=\pm26$.

Comment: it is $$(x^3-y)(x^3+y)=53$$

Comment: why the downvotes, did I kill somebody?

Comment: Since there's a solution by trial and error with $x=3$, perhaps there was a sense that you did not try very hard.

Comment: Oiue, although I did not downvote, I think I can explain why some people might: the style on this site is to show what you have already attempted, and also to explain the _context_ in which issues arise, so that people can respond more usefully to both you and to future inquiries and searches.

Answer (score 6):

$$x^6 = y^2 + 53$$
$$x^6-y^2 = 53$$
From $x^6-y^2 = (x^3+y)(x^3-y)$
$$(x^3+y)(x^3-y) = 53$$
The only factors of $53$ are $1$ and $53$ so let: $$x^3-y = 1$$$$x^3+y = 53$$
Adding the $2$ equations we get: $$2x^3 = 54$$ $$x = 3$$$$y = 3^3-1 = 26$$
Our solutions are $x = 3$, $y = 26$.
But notice that in the original equation we are raising $x$ to the $6^\text{th}$ power and $y$ to the $2^\text{nd}$ power so the signs on $x$ and $y$ can be changed so we get $$\boxed{x = \pm3, y = \pm26}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You can try write $x^6-y^2=(x^3-y)(x^3+y)$ and use the fact that 53 is a prime number.